# Codecvt doesn't work in gcc

Tags: c++, g++, locale, codecvt

I'm trying to use my own `codecvt` with standard iostreams. I'm using this line:

```
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale("C"), new rot13codecvt()));
```

`rot13codecvt` is just an example, shamelessly lifted verbatim from [the](https://github.com/jezhiggins/arabica/blob/master/include/convert/rot13codecvt.hpp) [interwebs](https://github.com/jezhiggins/arabica/blob/master/src/convert/rot13codecvt.cpp). A full runnable example is [here](http://ideone.com/5GIYvV). My real codecvt does something different.

As you can see in the linked live example, this doesn't *quite* work in g++. The output is not rot13d. No function from the custom codecvt class is ever called. But it works well in VS2012.

I have tried other locales beside "C" and none are working. Also tried an example [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stdcxx/trunk/examples/manual/locale.cpp), same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only file streams are required to use `std::codecvt<...>` and there is no requirement that any of the standard stream objects is implemented in terms of file streams. There are reasons for the implementers of either choice. Dinkumware's implementation uses `<stdio.h>` for most of its operations and it makes sense to use the same implementation under the hood in this case. libstdc++ avoids some overheads and directly accesses a buffer shared between the standard C and C++ streams and, thus, uses a different stream implementation.

When using file streams use of the `std::codecvt<...>` facets should be consistent.

Comment: Hm. Indeed, the standard only specifies that `filebuf` uses `codecvt`, not any other `streambuf`. That's rather annoying.

Answer (score 3):

The codecvt header exists as of gcc 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The libstdc++ provided with g++ doesn't implement the c++11 standard yet. On my version, the `<codecvt>` header is missing altogether.

```
f.jardon@xxxx 14:40:40 ~
$ find /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/ -name codecvt

f.jardon@xxxx 14:41:17 ~
```

And it's not the only thing missing:

```
f.jardon@xxxx 14:46:22 ~
$ grep -rl wbuffer_convert 'c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/'
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/cvt/wbuffer
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/cvt/xtest
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/xlocbuf

f.jardon@xxxx 14:46:25 ~
$ grep -rl wbuffer_convert /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/
```

Comment: Yes, in n3290 it is chapter: 22.5. "The header <codecvt> provides code conversion facets for various character encodings.", (codecvt_utf8, codecvt_ut16, codecvt_ut8_utf16).

Comment: @DietmarKühl `<codecvt>` export various UTF-related specializations of `std::codecvt`, which are indeed missing in g++/libstdc++. `std::codecvt` itself is still in `<locale>` and it's present in `g++`.